# npm ls gulp-util problems

Tags: firebase, npm, gulp

Hi I run the command: npm ls gulp-util

I do this because upon trying to install firebase: 'npm install firebase' I get the error: 
npm WARN deprecated gulp-util@3.0.8: gulp-util is deprecated - replace it, following the guidelines at https://medium.com/gulpjs/gulp-util-ca3b1f9f9ac5

I follow the command that the medium article suggests, I run it in my project folder as well as not in it, but it tells me: 
└── (empty)

Just trying to get clarification, I know the issue has been brought up but I have not seen a scenario where everything is empty, there is nothing to fix in terms of what the medium article mentions.